# Update Column value with subquery itself

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have an averages table and I want to update the column based on the previous rows. I was trying to do that with Inner join but it's not working.

```
UPDATE averages 
SET cost = (SELECT SUM(qty*cost)/SUM(qty) FROM averages averages_was
WHERE averages_was.order_number < averages.order_number
AND averages_was.product_id = averages.product_id
AND averages_was.branch_id = averages.branch_id)
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stack overflow! Can you provide your table structure including some sample data - preferably the INSERT and CREATE TABLE queries for us to simulate your concern.

Comment: hi bro i want to update record by record put SUM() previous column and set in next row

Comment: So can you provide us your table structures? Please refer to  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and modify your question.

Comment: I'm not sure  the statement can be run without fail as you use an subquery which involves the target table. Does it return ` ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'averages' for update in FROM clause` ?

Comment: Does the query make logical sense - you appear to be attempting to reset the cost on every row to the average cost

Comment: Use multiple-table UPDATE syntax. Calculate new average value in subquery (2 copies of table) and update 3rd table copy.